# A frame option in beamer that I can't figure out [h]

Tags: beamer

Does anyone know what

```
\begin{frame}[h]
  Content
\end{frame}
```

does? I can't seem to find it in the beamer user manual.

Comment: It generates an error: `[h]` is not a valid optional argument for `frame`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina My TexLive 2009 pdflatex compiles it without errors, and I can't find anything about it in the log file. What makes beamer ignore options it doesn't understand?

Comment: It all depends on how the options were implemented. In the most recent version of beamer (2013/12/02 3.33 in TeXLive 2014), the [h] option triggers the error message in my answer. beamer uses `keyval` to handle options, so it's possible that in previous versions, like the one you use, an unknown option was simply ignored, but in recent versions it will trigger the error message.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ok, that seems plausible, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good reason you didn't find it in the manual; `[h]` is *not* a valid optional argument for `frame`, so using it will trigger an error:

```
! Package keyval Error: h undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \begin{frame}[h] Content \end{frame}

?
```

The valid options for `frame` are described in pages 59 and 60 of the `beamer` manual.

Comment: It wasn't showing up as an error or warning in my texlive 2009 distribution of pdflatex with beamer version 3.10. It compiles fine. That's why I asked.